# Spring cloud stream application quits after one garbage input

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a problem with a Spring cloud stream application that is using the KStream component. It is listening to one input and directing messages to one output after processing them.

It is expecting a JSON string to come in and tries to convert it to a Spring Tuple on arrival. Reverse of this happens when sending the message out.

Problem is that when a Sysadmin wants to test a topic with a `kafka-console-producer.sh` for instance... and prints a string

> "lol"

in it, the whole Spring cloud stream application will die right there with the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'lol': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: lol; line: 1, column: 7]
    at org.springframework.tuple.JsonStringToTupleConverter.convert(JsonStringToTupleConverter.java:71) ~[spring-tuple-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.tuple.JsonStringToTupleConverter.convert(JsonStringToTupleConverter.java:31) ~[spring-tuple-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.tuple.TupleBuilder.fromString(TupleBuilder.java:153) ~[spring-tuple-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.TupleJsonMessageConverter.convertFromInternal(TupleJsonMessageConverter.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:175) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:167) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(CompositeMessageConverter.java:55) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kstream.KStreamListenerParameterAdapter$1.apply(KStreamListenerParameterAdapter.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:82) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:66) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:436) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:242) ~[kafka-streams-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'lol': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: lol; line: 1, column: 7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2839) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1903) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3850) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2397) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at org.springframework.tuple.JsonStringToTupleConverter.convert(JsonStringToTupleConverter.java:44) ~[spring-tuple-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I would expect that the framework has at least some fault tolerance for such behaviour. You cannot expect input to be nice and pretty always.
So I looked into Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_options

and there are some configuration options for what seems to be some hidden implementation of retry logic incase of failures. For instance the `maxAttempts` parameter. But this parameter already has the default value of 3 used and yet I don't see Spring cloud stream applications making any attempts to rescue from this error.

So I would like to know what is the recommended way of building some bad input tolerance for Spring cloud stream applications.

The configuration for the application looks like this:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        stream:
          bindings:
            input:
              content-type: application/json
              destination: inbound
              group: fraud
              consumer:
                headerMode: raw
            output:
              content-type: application/x-spring-tuple
              destination: outbound
              producer:
                headerMode: raw
                useNativeEncoding: true

spring.cloud.stream.kstream.binder.configuration:
  key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
  value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring Cloud Stream 1.3.x (Ditmars), there is only very limited support for error handling for Kafka Streams. In fact, it is up to the application to handle any errors in 1.3 kafka streams library. However, in 2.0.0, we are adding support for KIP-161. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-161%3A+streams+deserialization+exception+handlers

Using this new feature in 2.0.0 version of the kafka streams binder, you can either logAndSkip the records or logAndFail the records on deserialization errors. In addition to these, the binder also provides a DLQ sending exception handler implementation. Docs are still getting updated on the 2.0 line for all these. I will update the docs links here once thats ready. But, here is the gist of it.

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.serdeError: sendToDlq` (or logAndFail or logAndSkip)

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.stream.bindings.input.consumer.dlqName:[dlq name]` - If this is not provided it will be `error.[incoming-topic].[group-name]`.

Then you will see the records in error from deserialization in the DLQ topic. 
Once again, these features are only available in the 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and will be part of the upcoming `2.0.0.RC1` release.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! 
Would you have any rough date to add for the RC of 2.0.0? Have to make a decision about implementing my own handling or using newest code.

Comment: 2.0.0.RC1 should be out next week.